# Suppressing URL dates without removing Retrieved from keyword while using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, apa-style, scrreprt

I am using `scrreprt` document class for writing a thesis report. Using APA style citation for bibliography.

Currently I have added *urldata* in `.bib` in order to show the retrieved keyword. Using below lines

```
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
```

Citation displayed is

> Author name year. Title. Retrieved June 22, 2020, from https://research_url.pdf.

How can I suppress the date from citation and just have the **Retreived from** keyword for the URL alone?

Somthing like:

> Author name year. Title. Retrieved from https://research_url.pdf

as shown in [this article](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/apa-citation-guide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "retrieved from" is only shown if a `urldate` is present. It is my understanding that that is what the APA manual requires. If this is not the case, please open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa.

Here is how you can tell `biblatex-apa` to print the "retrieved from" regardless of the presence of `urldate`.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{url}\OR\NOT\iffieldundef{doi}}
    {}
    {\bibstring{retrieved}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \iffieldundef{urlyear}
      {}
      {\printurldate
       \setunit{\urldatecomma}}%
     \bibstring{from}%
     \setunit{\addspace}
     \iffieldundef{url}{}{\printfield{url}\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\relax}}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{elk,
  author   = {Anne Elk},
  title    = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  url      = {http://www.example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  date     = {1972-01-01},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{ctan,elk}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, A. (1972, January 1). A theory on brontosauruses. Retrieved from http://www.example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf]

If you want to get rid of all `urldate`s automatically, add

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
      }
   }
}
```

to the preamble

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a ton moewe

Comment: @user200 If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left of the answer. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers